# Chrome Extension - Cant get input value

Tags: javascript, html, input, local-storage, add-on

I am trying to get input value and make it into var to change webpage value. I dont know if it is the right way to do it but as far as i know it is :/ I kinda need to make autofiller which fills page from my extensions input. I tried to do it when it directly searches for my input.value but it always shows its null, and I also tried to save my input in localStorage... But it dont work :( I will post everything when i tried to do it when I save my input in localStorage.
Sorry if this is a stupid question but I just cant get it to work :(

Manifest file:

```
{
"manifest_version" : 2,
"name": "sAVING iNPUT",
"version": "1.0",
"description" : "Click something pls",
"version" : "1.0",
"permissions" : ["<all_urls>"],

"browser_action" : {
  "default_popup" : "popup.html"

}
}
```

Popup.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title> activity</title></head>
<body>
<div>
    <div>
        E-Pasts
        <input type="text" name="epasts" id="epasts"></input>
    </div>
    <button id="ielogoties" aonClick="saveInput()" > login </button>
</div>
    <script src="popup.js">
    function saveInput(){
        localStorage.setItem("epastss", document.getElementById("epasts"));
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Popup.js file:

```
 function injectTheScript() {
chrome.tabs.query({active : true, currentWindow:true},function(tabs){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id,{file: "content_script.js"});
});

}
document.getElementById("ielogoties").addEventListener
("click",injectTheScript);
```

content_script.js file:

```
var drepasts = document.getElementById("email");
var epasts = localStorage.getItem("epastss")


drepasts.value= epasts;
alert("hehejr");
localStorage.removeItem("epasts");
```

Now I am getting this error when I press button:

Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Comment: Check the solution here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455598/get-input-value-chrome-extension/52455916#52455916

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `storage` permission in your manifest file in order to access `localStorage`.

Your `permissions` section should look like this:

```
"permissions" : ["<all_urls>", "storage"],
```

Or:

```
"permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "storage"
],
```

See the [chrome.storage documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) for more information.

---

Also, I'm guessing this is just a typo in your post, but `aonClick` should be `onclick`:

```
<button id="ielogoties" aonClick="saveInput()" > login </button>
```

---

The way your code is right now, it's grabbing the `<input>` element itself and saving that in `localStorage`, then retrieving that value and trying to insert it into the element with id of "email". That could be why you're getting `null`.

To get the input value instead of the input element, change your `setItem` statement to this:

```
localStorage.setItem("epastss", document.getElementById("epasts").value);
```

Comment: Its a dumb mistake by me, but it still shows up as null :(

Comment: @TheProfesor Are you trying to save the input element, or its value? If you want to save its value, you need to change your `setItem` value to `document.getElementById("epasts").value`.