# Get input value Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Here is my **popup.js**

```
let $token1= $('#token1').val(); 
let $token2= $('#token2').val();
let $token3= $('#token3').val();

if(true){
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    { token: ['tokens', $token1, $token2, $token3]},
    myFunction());
}
```

And here is the **background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse){ 
if(message.token[0] == "tokens"){
    let $token1 = message.token[1];
    let $token2 = message.token[2];
    let $token3 = message.token[3];
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "file.js"}, myFunction());
}
```

when I put the value as attribute into html like this 
`<input type="text" id="token1" value="token1">`  it works correctly,

but when I remove the value attribute `<input type="text" id="token1">` the value is empty

I don't need to use storage at this time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it!

here is so simple:)

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
{ token: ['tokens', $token1 = $('#token1').val(), $token2 = $('#token2').val(), $token3 = $('#token3').val()]},
myFunction());
```

}

Hope it somebody Helps )